# The installation of the package printed by electron forge failed

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

The application packaged through electron forge on the Windows 11 system failed to install on some Windows 10, with the error shown in the following figure. If the installation package for the same project can be successfully installed on this Windows 10 through electron forge, what is the reason for this?

[image]

Hope to help identify the problem